# Is it possible to use multiple dispatch without knowing the type?

Tags: python, oop, multiple-dispatch

Using multiple dispatch to allow for function overloading within OOP, is it possible for me to run the following code:

```
@dispatch(int)
  def __init__(self, radius: int):
```

However, remove the int, as the attribute being passed in could either be an int or a str.

Comment: What's the point of overloading if you accept any type?

Comment: @matszwecja I am completing a programming trail and I am NOT allowed to change the initial code, there are instances where 1 is passed in and instances where "one" is passed in, I can obviously do:


if x == "one":
    x = 1


But as I am not allowed to change the original code I HAVE to do it within my class, I could duplicate the above text for str but then I would have to do it for a lot of different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`functools.singledispatchmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) to overload a class method by its arguments' annotation.

```py
from functools import singledispatchmethod


class Generic:
    """
    >>> _ = Generic(1)
    __init__ got int
    >>> _ = Generic(1.0)
    __init__ got float
    >>> _ = Generic(None)
    default __init__
    """

    @singledispatchmethod
    def __init__(self, radius):
        print("default __init__")

    @__init__.register
    def _(self, radius: int):
        print("__init__ got int")

    @__init__.register
    def _(self, radius: float):
        print("__init__ got float")
```